# How can I determine if Akka bytestring contains a given substring?

Tags: scala, akka

Given a sample text file, how can one use Akka ByteStrings and either convert it to plain text or run a "find" on the ByteString itself?

```
            val file = new File("sample.txt")
            val fileSource = SynchronousFileSource(file, 4096)
            val messageStream = fileSource.map(chunk => sendMessage(chunk.toString()))
            messageStream.to(Sink.foreach(println(_))).run
```

The "toString()" functionality above literally spits out a string containing the text "ByteString", followed by bytes represented as integers. For example:

```
            chunk.toString() ==> "ByteString(111, 112, 119, 111)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `containsSlice` to find sub ByteString.

```
scala> import akka.util.ByteString;
import akka.util.ByteString

scala> val target = ByteString("hello world");
target: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100)

scala> val sub = ByteString("world")
sub: akka.util.ByteString = ByteString(119, 111, 114, 108, 100)

scala> target.containsSlice(sub)
res0: Boolean = true
```

If you want to convert `akka.util.ByteString` to `String`, you can use `decodeString`

```
scala> ByteString("hello").decodeString("UTF-8")
res3: String = hello
```

See the doc for more detail: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.13/index.html#akka.util.ByteString

Comment: perfect, just found it in docs and came back to post back.. lo and behold, already solved! thanks.